# How to load Dojo modules defined in the same file

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

Say I have this cool module that loads and manipulates a data grid.

```
require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!'],
    function(lang, DataGrid, dom){
    var data = {
.....
});
```

I would like all its dependencies to reside on *one* self-contained file.

```
<script> ** /dom/dom.js defined here** </script>
<script> ** dojox/grid/DataGrid.js defined here** </script>
<script> ** data grid module here *** </script>
```

i.e. I don't want any reference to external or local file system.
This is not for a website. I just want to make use of dojo widgets in a single user desktop app.

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/. But your example looks like 3 files to me and not one; `dom.js`, `DataGrid.js` and module. Did you mean to only have a single `<script>` import?

Comment: @Paul What I mean is the 3 files are not imported to but their code is contained ( copy pasted ) within the script tags.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to build all your required files into a single file using the dojo build tool. Simply add all the files/modules you need as a single layer in the xml file and build it.

In this way you can maintain all required file list in the xml file and run the build tool to create one big js file which you can always include in you desktop app.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/

Add a layer as such

```
layers : {
 "all/all":{
    include:["dojo/dojo","dojo/i18n","dojo/ready","dojo/domReady"]
 }
}
```